# VS Code | Python program | module import process not happening

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

### Environment

I have a Python quickstart in VS Code as part of a multi-root workspace. I have manually added 3 files; **tasks.json**, **settings.json** and **launch.json**.

### Unexpected behaviour

When i debug the project, *the main script fails because of missing modules*. This is because on start-up the modules listed in **requirements.txt** are not being installed.

### Tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "pipInstall",
        "type": "shell",
        "osx": {
          "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
        },
        "windows": {
          "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
        },
        "linux": {
          "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

### Launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\batch-python-quickstart\\src\\python_quickstart_client.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python Virtual Environments\\myenvid\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why the modules were not installed

The modules specified in the requirement.txt file were not being installed because there was no reference to the **tasks.json** in the **launch.json**. To execute the tasks before executing the python app requires `"preLaunchTask": "pipInstall"` to reference the task named `pipInstall` in tasks.json.

### Code after changes

**Note**: I also fixed some incorrect paths and moved my virtual environments to a new directory **outside** my projects.

#### Settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\thepath\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

#### Launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\batch-python-quickstart\\src\\python_quickstart_client.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "preLaunchTask": "pipInstall"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "pipInstall",
        "type": "shell",
        "osx": {
          "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
        },
        "windows": {
          "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
        },
        "linux": {
          "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\batch-python-quickstart\\src"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

### Furthermore

It is possible to cascade tasks by adding the same dependency property inside a task; `"dependsOn": "othertasklabel"`. Ideal for a set of build steps.